# Consolidating site CSS sheets

Tags: 7, theming

As I'm moving on to the markup/stylesheet work on my site, I noticed that there are quite a bunch of CSS references to modules. Not only does it clutter the page markup, but it also refers to core Drupal modules, such as `/modules/field/theme/field.css`.

Since I have to override some of the style definitions (clear problematic floats, narrow a context, and some such), at the same time a question raises in my head - how do you guys approach those stylesheets: do you paste all the definitions in your theme css and remove unneeded css stylesheet links - or rather: - leave the stuff in place and override all problematic style definitions in your theme css?

How do you approach module-related stylesheets, such as Display Suite layouts?

I would like to avoid redundancy where possible, but only when the effort is justifiable.
Any insights?

Comment: Can't you just aggregate the CSS in the performance section of your site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal will aggregate all of your style sheets into one when you enable it at admin/config/development/performance (Don't set it during development).

[image]

If you feel there is too many redundant stylesheets, you can use a module like [Omega Tools](http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) which allows you to completely disable stylesheets provided by modules (even core).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - I'm going to play with OT to see what they do. Thanks